# How can I hide the on-screen keyboard when testing a web app on Chrome on Android via BrowserStack?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, browserstack

I am testing a web app with BrowserStack in this style (C#):

```cs
var driverOptions = createDriverOptions(); // ChromeOptions etc. 
driverOptions.AddAdditionalOption("bstack:options", browserStackOptionsDictionary); 
new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(browserStackUrl), driverOptions);
```

This works for all browsers on desktop OSes and Safari on iOS.

However, with Chrome on Android I run into a problem: After sending text to an input element, the on-screen keyboard sometimes stays open, causing a subsequent button click command to fail.

I have tried `driver.Navigate().Back()`, but it always performs actual navigation. I have also found the following proposals:

```cs
driver.HideKeyboard()
driver.GetKeyboard().SendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.SendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

But I assume these require Appium - is that correct? If so, how can I use Appium to test a web app via BrowserStack? I have found these docs, but I assume they apply only to native apps (APK): https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop

Comment: Could you try by tapping somewhere on the screen after device keyboard usage?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, when the keyboard is shown, the remaining screen real estate is very small, so I am not sure there can always be an element that can be clicked without performing an action. But I will have a look.

Comment: To elaborate, it must be a "no-action" element, because the keyboard does not reliably pop up after every usage of a text box, so I don't know when the click would be just a click that closes the keyboard or an actual click.

Comment: You can use the Appium driver to run your tests on Automate on Browserstack.
You can simply initiate the driver through Appium instead of Selenium and this will help you run the Appium commands. 

I hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: @grandEL-dsouza Can you please share a (pseudo) code example of driver initialization?

Comment: Hey @MarcoEckstein

Please consider the following:

You need to import Webdriver from Appium instead of Selenium in your code like this:

from appium import webdriver

this will cause your code to initiate a webdriver with Appium and thus you can achieve your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dependency to the *Appium.WebDriver* library. If you are using Selenium 4, you will have to use Appium.WebDriver 5, which is currently only available as a prerelease, the latest of which is 5.0.0-rc.1.

Then simply replace `RemoteWebDriver` with `AndroidDriver` from namespace `OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android`. Now you can use `driver.HideKeyboard()`.